# MobileFirst ant scripts for build with minification

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been building an application and have been using MobileFirst minification activated in the Studio. 
Now i am developing ant scripts and can't seem to find a property to activate minification during the ant build.

I have my build-settings.xml properly configured but my ant builds don't generate minified code. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attributes **concatenate**="true" and **minifyResources**="true" in the builder element.