# Minification and Concatenation in MobileFirst

Tags: android, ant, minify, ibm-mobilefirst, mobile-application

I am trying to Minify and concat my Web-resources of Mobile App using build-settings.xml by following code

```
<buildSettings xmlns="http://www.ibm.worklight.com/build-settings">
<common>
<minification level="simple" includes="**"/>
<concatenation includes="**"/>
</common>
<android>
    <minification includes="**" level="simple"/>
    <concatenation includes="**"/>
</android>
<iphone>
    <minification includes="**" level="whitespaces"/>
    <concatenation includes="**"/>
</iphone>
</buildSettings>
```

After building App, I am not able to see Minified and concat(size of APK and IPA file is same) effect on web-resources
Also, when MobileFirst build-setting Minifiy and concat web-resources, like at the time of MobileFirst build or during Platform specific build(generation of APK and/or IPA)

MF version: 7.1.0.00.20160229-1240

Using ANT scripts for MobileFirst, Android and iOS build

Answer (score 1):

When using minification and concatenation, and the build task is executed via an Ant script, ensure that your build task in the Ant script also includes `concatenate="true"` and `minifyResources="true"`.

Reference: [MobileFirst ant scripts for build with minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286200/mobilefirst-ant-scripts-for-build-with-minification)

Comment: are these attribute part of **app-builder** element?

Comment: I believe so. Yes.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, but minification is too slow, earlier I was able to generate build in 2 min, now its taking more than 70 minutes. Any idea how to speed up?

Comment: I have no idea why it would take you 70 minutes.